# Command-line file copy to remote share with different login

Tags: file, command-line, copy

I want to copy a file to a remote location.  This task will run from SQL Server (Agent) scheduler, and thus the COPY will run under the SQL Service account, and I don't want to create matching credentials on the remote machine.

Only way I figured was:

NET USE X: \RemoteServer\RemoteShare ThePassword /USER:RemoteUserID

then I can run a command to copy to X:

However, X: cannot be relied upon to be persistent, so I came up with:

```
NET USE X: /DELETE
NET USE X: \\RemoteServer\RemoteShare ThePassword /USER:RemoteUserID
COPY MyFile X:
NET USE X: /DELETE
```

and ignored the initial delete if X: was not already mapped (which should only be the case if something else mapped X:, or a previous copy died half way through)

But I have got the message

"*There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to X:.*

Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]:"

apparently there is an undocumented /Y parameter which solves that:

```
NET USE X: /DELETE /Y
NET USE X: \\RemoteServer\RemoteShare ThePassword /USER:RemoteUserID
COPY MyFile X:
NET USE X: /DELETE
```

however ... the likely cause would be that another instance of my command is running, and by removing the X: mapping I will kill off that file-copy operation ... not good ...

I'd appreciate advice on ways around this, or other ways to copy a file to a remote share, including logging in, from a command-prompt.

Background:

The files being copied are 100GB's, and I am using ROBOCOPY to make the filecopy. I cannot just let RoboCopy "mirror" the folder, as only specific files are to be copied, and there are different RoboCopy commands / destinations etc. for different files.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go around things the other way around:
create a shared folder on your computer that is accessible to all users.
when you want to copy the file, place it on that folder, and then use psexec (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to run the copy command remotely (copy the file from the shared folder on your computer).

Hope this helps